how to draw this bar chart in latex?
I am trying to replicate a plot like this one in latex. I wonder if anyone has some good example codes to share? many thanks,


It's more a drawing, less a bar chart. So I suggest to peek into the pgf-manual, e.g. here: https://tikz.dev/tutorials-guidelines . Th eelements you'll need from it are node[draw,fill=blue] (bar), draw[->] (for the arrows), node[anchor= ...] (labels). For the brace there are several options. // I suggest to try a little and add code, better sooner than later, to your question.

Something to get you started; keys:

absolute positions AND related to the nodes anchors
you could switch to matrix placement for more flexibility
place basic elements first
introduce and modify styles as needed
choose your favorite color model from LaTeX or TikZ

From a refactoring perspective the \draw commands qualify for standardization, e.g as a \newcommand.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    trt/.style={anchor=west},
    bb/.style={ draw,fill=blue!100!cyan!50,
                inner sep=0mm,minimum height=5mm,anchor=west},
    >={Stealth},
    an/.style={anchor=north},
 ] 
    % ~~~ entry ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[trt]  (T1) at (0,0) {Treated};
    % ~~~ "bars" ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[bb,minimum width=4cm] (B1) at (3,0) {};
    \node[bb,minimum width=2cm] (B2) at (B1.east) {};
    % ~~~ arrows ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[<-] (B1.south west) -- +(0,-.4) node[an] {Start of follow-up};
    \draw[<-] (B1.south east) -- +(0,-.4) node[an] {First prescription};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


this is great!  I will try it.
